# Spring Security 5: Can't redirect to initial URL after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The questions should be pretty simple. Based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint.

I have 2 clients:

- spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.**a**
- spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.**b**

I also configured the authentication to be made against a SSO Service (oAuth2).

The authentication is working nicely, what does not work is the following:

- I go to localhost/team (which is protected under authentication)
- I am redirected to the Spring Boot screen where I need to select one of the 2 clients: a or b
- I select a -> I authenticate
- After authentication I am sent to localhost instead of localhost/team

I have no idea how to redirect the user back to localhost/team because after authentication I lose the original "Referer". The available "Referer" is from my Identity Provided and it does not help me. Any ideas?

I am using Spring Boot 2, V. 2.3.1 with Spring Security 5.x

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. The sessionCreationPolicy was set to IF_REQUIRED instead of ALWAYS.

I can confirm that with sessionCreationPolicy ALWAYS it works.

I hope it will help other people as well.